# Aggregation in flask-mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm just staring out with MongoDB and I'm staring an application with flask-mongoengine and I want to aggregate a few documents.

I'm using flask-mongoengine and when trying

```
class MyDocumentModel(db.Document):
  name = db.StringField(max_length=55)

MyDocumentModel.objects.aggregate()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'aggregate'

Comment: Can you clarify how you want aggregate documents? Probably you need aggregation methods: https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#aggregation.

Comment: You need to use raw pymongo and aggregate functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with mongoengine v0.9 (which is currently in development), you will be able to use `aggregate()`, like you suggested: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate

Until then, you need to rely on `pymongo`: [Flask-MongoEngine & PyMongo Aggregation Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415045/flask-mongoengine-pymongo-aggregation-query)