# Flask-MongoEngine & PyMongo Aggregation Query

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to make an aggregation query using flask-mongoengine, and from what I have read it does not sound like it is possible.

I have looked over several forum threads, e-mail chains and a few questions on Stack Overflow, but I have not found a really good example of how to implement aggregation with flask-mongoengine.

There is a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954830/aggregation-in-flask-mongoengine) that says you have to use "raw pymongo and aggregation functionality."  However, there is no examples of how that might work. I have tinkered with Python and have a basic application up using Flask framework, but delving into full fledged applications & connecting/querying to Mongo is pretty new to me.

Can someone provide an example (or link to an example) of how I might utilize my flask-mongoengine models, but query using the aggregation framework with PyMongo?
Will this require two connections to MongoDB (one for PyMongo to perform the aggregation query, and a second for the regular query/insert/updating via MongoEngine)?

An example of the aggregation query I would like to perform is as follows (this query gets me exactly the information I want in the Mongo shell):

```
db.entry.aggregate([
    { '$group' : 
        { '_id' : { 'carrier' : '$carrierA', 'category' : '$category' }, 
          'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

An example of the output from this query:

```
{ "_id" : { "carrier" : "Carrier 1", "category" : "XYZ" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "carrier" : "Carrier 1", "category" : "ABC" }, "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : { "carrier" : "Carrier 2", "category" : "XYZ" }, "count" : 31 }
{ "_id" : { "carrier" : "Carrier 2", "category" : "ABC" }, "count" : 6 }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The class your define with Mongoengine actually has a `_get_collection()` method which gets the "raw" collection object as implemented in the pymongo driver.

I'm just using the name `Model` here as a placeholder for your actual class defined for the connection in this example:

```
Model._get_collection().aggregate([
    { '$group' : 
        { '_id' : { 'carrier' : '$carrierA', 'category' : '$category' }, 
          'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

So you can always access the pymongo objects without establishing a separate connection. Mongoengine is itself build upon pymongo.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. This has been a bit of a headache for me trying to find a solution.  I tested with the "_get_collection()" method and was able to get the output from Mongo.

Comment: Brilliant answer!! Just to add to this, if you want to run the group by clause on only certain records, you can use the $match operator as follows:  


 `Model._get_collection().aggregate([
     {
            '$match': qs._query,
     },
    { '$group' : 
        { '_id' : { 'carrier' : '$carrierA', 'category' : '$category' }, 
          'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
        }
    }
    ])`

where qs is an instance of MongoEngine queryset.

Answer (score 12):

`aggregate` is available since Mongoengine 0.9.
Link to the [API Reference](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate).

As there is no example whatsoever around, here is how you perform an aggregate query using aggregation framework with Mongoengine > 0.9

```
pipeline = [
  { '$group' : 
    { '_id' : { 'carrier' : '$carrierA', 'category' : '$category' }, 
      'count' : { '$sum' : 1 }
    }
  }]

Model.objects().aggregate(*pipeline)
```