# How to do "group by" in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Suppose my Schema looks like so:

```
class User(Document):
  username = StringField()
  password = StringField()
  category = StringField()
```

Imagine we have these existing categories: `"avengers", "justice-leaguers", "villains"`, and I want to perform a `"group by"` query for `User.objects.all()` so that I can get something like this:

```
[
 [<User: IronMan object>, <User: Thor object>, <User: Hulk object>], 
 [<User: Superman object>,<User: Batman object>], 
 [<User: Ultron object>, <User: Joker object>, <User: LexLuthor object>]
]
```

Or better yet:

```
{
 "avengers": [<User: IronMan object>, <User: Thor object>, <User: Hulk object>], 
 "justice-leaguers": [<User: Superman object>,<User: Batman object>], 
 "villains": [<User: Ultron object>, <User: Joker object>, <User: LexLuthor object>]
}
```

I looked into MongoEngine's docs and have yet to find anything helpful. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), you only need to `$group` documents by category:

```
db.User.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { _id: "$category", username: { $push: "$username" }}
  }
])
```

Using the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) aggregation function, you will build an array containing all the username sharing the same category.

Given you sample data:

```
> db.User.find({},{category:1,username:1,_id:0})
{ "category" : "avengers", "username" : "IronMan" }
{ "category" : "avengers", "username" : "Thor" }
{ "category" : "avengers", "username" : "Hulk" }
{ "category" : "justice-leagers", "username" : "Superman" }
{ "category" : "justice-leagers", "username" : "Batman" }
{ "category" : "villains", "username" : "Ultron" }
{ "category" : "villains", "username" : "Joker" }
{ "category" : "villains", "username" : "LexLuthor" }
```

This will produce:

```
{ "_id" : "villains", "username" : [ "Ultron", "Joker", "LexLuthor" ] }
{ "_id" : "justice-leagers", "username" : [ "Superman", "Batman" ] }
{ "_id" : "avengers", "username" : [ "IronMan", "Thor", "Hulk" ] }
```

Comment: Any chance this could be done using Mongoengine? I'm very likely to do this in my python code instead of the mongo shell. Thanks again!

Comment: @benjaminz I don't have access to Mongoengine (and have never used it), but it appears to have the required API: [mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate(*pipeline, **kwargs)](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate)

Comment: Do check out this answer : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24420848/1882331) for using 'group by' in mongoengine.

Comment: Is it possible to add where conditions in these queries?

Answer (score 20):

Since the OP asked for mongoengine (and thats what I needed) here is an example of this using mongoengine:

```
categories = User.objects.aggregate([{
    '$group': { '_id': '$category', 'username': { '$push': '$username' }}
}])
```

This will return a pymongo command cursor iterator.

```
print list(categories)
```

Will return:

```
[{ "_id": "villains", "username": ["Ultron", "Joker", "LexLuthor"]},
 { "_id": "justice-leagers", "username": ["Superman", "Batman"]},
 { "_id": "avengers", "username": ["IronMan", "Thor", "Hulk"]}]
```

Comment: @SolessChong it is proper syntax all right. It is a python list of dictionaries. The reason it does not work anymore is possibly a change in mongoengine's aggregate. To make it work simply dismiss the list: `User.objects.aggregate({...})` instead of `([{...}])`.

Comment: @Wtower See the edit on Nov 21. The answer has corrected syntax error.

Comment: @SolessChong alright, thanks for clearing this up. Nevertheless, the comment regarding the list is applicable currently.

Comment: @Realistic, thanks for your answer! Would you mind updating it with the syntax of an example when you have more than one category to group by. This is what would work in the CLI  `$group : {_id : {one:"$one", two:"$two"}` but code says "can not encode the object".