# Mongoengine aggregate $match primary key (_id) is not working

Tags: python-3.x, match, aggregate, mongoengine

I'm trying to use aggregate with mongoengine. Also, it was challenging to find out, how this works (because there is nothing about it in the documentation), I've made a little progress.

But I can't match a primary key:

```
from mongoengine import *

connect('test')


class User(Document):
    username = StringField()

    def match_test_username(self):
        pipeline = [{ "$match": {"username": self.username} }]
        return User.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)

    def match_test_id(self):
        pipeline = [{ "$match": {"id": self.id} }]
        return User.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)


mary = User(username="mary")
mary.save()
mary.reload()


agg_username = mary.match_test_username
for doc in agg_username():
    print("match_test_username:", doc)

agg_id = mary.match_test_id
for doc in agg_id():
    print("match_test_id:", doc)
```

If you run this, matching is working for the username (match_test_username), but I can't get it to work with the primary key, I've tried key name: _id, pk, id.

What do I wrong?

And is there any Documentation about this? All I found is this: [Flask-MongoEngine & PyMongo Aggregation Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415045/flask-mongoengine-pymongo-aggregation-query#24420848) what was very helpful.

What also would help, is there a better way ("pythonic way") to iterate over the findings?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in your query type of the ID as `ObjectId`. So you should do this:

```
pipeline = [{ "$match": {"_id": ObjectId(self.id)} }]
return User.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your fast answer! But:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matchtest.py", line 28, in <module>
    for doc in agg_id():
  File "matchtest.py", line 14, in match_test_id
    pipeline = [{ "$match": {"_id": ObjectId(self.id)} }]
NameError: name 'ObjectId' is not defined`

Comment: of course you should import it.  `from bson import ObjectId`

Comment: :-| **IT WORKS - THANK YOU VERY MUCH!** :-) Is there a _special place_ on the Internet, where I can read more about the relation mongoengine, BSON? Where do you know this from?

Comment: Bson is the data interchange format which used by Mongo db as data storage and network transfer format. Bson is binary encoded format which extends JSON. Few links to check:

http://bsonspec.org/
https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson

Comment: OK, when I read about MongoDB, I read about that of course, but I thought, mongoengine would take care of this dependency. Thank you again!